# Overriding bootstrap 4 $primary variable not applied on all overriden bootstrap variables when using in _user-variables.scss

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I am making one HTML theme using BootStrap 4.3.1. My goal is to override $primary color variable in my theme _user-variables.scss that I think, It should change all colors according to theme _variables.scss in my theme. I am new to BootStrap 4 so please could you be kind enough to help me instead of marking my question flagged/duplicated?

I will give one example here that what I want to achieve:

I think that according to my knowledge, by overriding just $primary color variable in my _user-variables.scss should also change the color of every elements that is set to use directly $primary color in theme _variables.scss. Is this correct or I am doing anything wrong here?

My theme style.scss:

```
// Theme variables and mixins 
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";

// User Variables
@import "user-variables";

@import "../vendor/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/scss/variables";

// Bootstrap core
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I have put this much code in my theme _variables.scss and this is working fine:

```
$primary: #4cbd89;
$link-color: $primary;
$navbar-dark-hover-color: $primary;
$navbar-dark-active-color: $primary;
$navbar-light-hover-color: $primary;
$navbar-light-active-color: $primary;
```

I am trying to override above custom variables in _user-variables.scss like below:

```
$primary: #f00f00;
```

I am guessing overriding primary color in user-variables.scss should automatically change the value of 5 properties residing in custom.scss or Do i need to put that in my user-variables.scss? I don't know what is the best way. Anyone can please help me?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Change all the `primary` colors to `#f00f00`?

Comment: @Zim Thank you so much for your response. I was expecting answer from you :)

Yes I want to change all the colors to #f00f000 and to make my theme more user friendly, I want to allow users to change color from one variable only so that will be applied to all five values I have listed in my above theme _variables.scss. So if user just add $primary: #f00f00 variables in _user-variables.scss so all 5 values in theme _variables.scss will be #f00f00. Sorry if I am making any confusion for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the way you have defined the SCSS, *only* link colors and navbar links (`$link-color, $navbar-dark-hover-color, $navbar-dark-active-color, $navbar-light-hover-color and $navbar-light-active-color`) will be `#4cbd89`. All other `$primary` classes will use `$primary: #f00f00` since that's the *last* override definition of $primary you're using before the `bootstrap.scss`.

If you want the user vars to *optionally* (only when specified) override the theme vars you need to...

Give the **theme variables** the `!default` flag..

```
$primary: #4cbd89 !default;
$link-color: $primary !default;
$navbar-dark-hover-color: $primary !default;
$navbar-dark-active-color: $primary !default;
$navbar-light-hover-color: $primary !default;
$navbar-light-active-color: $primary !default;
```

Put the **user variables** *before* the theme variables.

```
// User Variables
@import "user-variables";

// Custom Theme variables and mixins 
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";

// Bootstrap core
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Also, there's no reason to `@import /scss/bootstrap/functions` and `/scss/bootstrap/variables` before /scss/bootstrap since `/scss/bootstrap.scss` already imports those files.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/8VyTjEPq4j